# Prestashop webservice problem with suppliers

Tags: xml, web-services, prestashop

I am inserting products into Prestashop using the webservice in XML format and I managed to do this, but I have a problem when setting the supplier id.
From the XML I can set a supplier id which is used as the default supplier, but if I modify the product from the admin interface, the supplier id is unset because on the left part there is a checkbox list with suppliers and no supplier is checked. If I check the supplier, on the right part there is the default supplier which is set correctly as the supplier with the id I just set.

So basically, I need a way to set the suppliers array from the webservice and I couldn't find a way to do this. I tried product_suppliers, but when I make a GET request to this endpoint, I get the products associated to that supplier and not the suppliers associated with that product.

I also tried to make a GET product request before setting multiple suppliers and right after, but nothing is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
If anybody needs this info in the future,
Make a POST request to api/product_suppliers with the following XML to attach new supplier to a product

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <product_supplier>
        <id_product></id_product>
        <id_product_attribute></id_product_attribute>
        <id_supplier></id_supplier>
    </product_supplier>
</prestashop>
```